# Bootstrap Scrollspy won't work with floated content (spanX)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Scrollspy doesn't seem to work with the built in bootstrap "spanX" classes, for example:

**This Works**

```
 <body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#scrollspy-nav">
     <div id="scrollspy-nav" class="span4">
         <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked affix">
             <li><a href="#test1">Section 1</a></li>
             <li><a href="#test2">Section 2</a></li>
             <li><a href="#test3">Section 3</a></li>
         </ul>
     </div>
     <div>
         <section id="test1">Test 1 <!-- Lots of <br/>'s --></section>
         <section id="test2">Test 2 <!-- Lots of <br/>'s --></section>
         <section id="test3">Test 3 <!-- Lots of <br/>'s --></section>
     </div>
  </body>
```

**This does not:**

```
 <body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#scrollspy-nav">
     <div id="scrollspy-nav" class="span4">
         <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked affix">
             <li><a href="#test1">Section 1</a></li>
             <li><a href="#test2">Section 2</a></li>
             <li><a href="#test3">Section 3</a></li>
         </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="span8">
         <section id="test1">Test 1 <!-- Lots of <br/>'s --></section>
         <section id="test2">Test 2 <!-- Lots of <br/>'s --></section>
         <section id="test3">Test 3 <!-- Lots of <br/>'s --></section>
     </div>
  </body>
```

The first example (the one that works), does not have a spanX class on the content container div.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple two column layout, create a **.row** and add the appropriate number of *.span* columns. As this is a 12-column grid, each .span* spans a number of those 12 columns, and should always add up to 12 for each row (or the number of columns in the parent).

```
   <div class="row">
      <div class="span4">...</div>
      <div class="span8">...</div>
   </div>
```

© [twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem)